# std::thread as member of class executing random thread causing an abort at asignate thread

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, c++11, android-ndk

In my class I have thread object as public membe:

```
class AppManager{
   ...
    public:
    std::thread m_thread;
};
```

Then when I initialize the thread:

```
void* BridgeFunction(void *pctx) {
    ((AppManager*)pctx)->MainAppThread();
    return 0;
}

void AppManager::CreateAppThread(){
   m_thread = std::thread(&BridgeFunction, this);
   m_thread.detach();
}
```

I got an Abort on std::terminate:

```
 thread& operator=(thread&& __t) noexcept
    {
      if (joinable())
      std::terminate();
      swap(__t);
      return *this;
    }
```

Why? I'm calling detach, I tried changing from:

```
m_thread = std::thread(&BridgeFunction, this);
```

To:

```
m_thread = std::thread(&AppManager::MainAppThread, this);
```

And the same, it works only if I declare the m_thread as global and I debugged why it works, turns out that the thread declared as member execute a random thread **before** I assign the thread, I know this because I printed the id to see if it was joinable:

```
    auto myid = m_thread.get_id();
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << myid;
    std::string thread_id = ss.str();

    LogPrintDebug("[Thread Activity] -  Id of thread not created yet: %s", thread_id.c_str());

    m_thread = std::thread(&BridgeFunction, this);
    m_thread.detach();
```

It prints:

```
[Thread Activity] - Id of thread not created yet: 1074643408
```

When I declare global the thread it prints:

```
[Thread Activity] - Id of thread not created yet::id of a non-executing thread
```

I printed also the Id of my actual thread and it's different than the Id of the random thread, so try to terminate it due to the part:

```
if (joinable())
 std::terminate();
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 running an Android Native Activity using Clang 3.6 and the GNU STL libraries, ndk r10e.

I tested the same code on windows and the id of the thread is 0, doesn't get any Abort.

Thanks

Comment: If you detach `m_thread` on all codepaths, then why did you make it a member in the first place? You may just as well do `std::thread(&BridgeFunction, this).detach();` and not assign the thread to any variable. The symptoms suggest that elsewhere, you do assign a thread to `m_thread` and keep it attached.

Comment: I would use the same class for other platforms, in the case of Win32 I use join for the same thread, in Android I need to detach it, I have several #ifdefs that I excluded in the code snippet. I'm starting to believe it's a bug of the ndk, I need to do more test (changing target platforms and stl libraries).